# How to know or set a PCI/PCIe device address map?

Tags: c, kernel, hardware, pci

I'm trying to understand how to instruct the CPU to instruct a PCI device to map its memory to the physical address of the CPU.

I've read https://wiki.osdev.org/PCI#Memory_Mapped_PCI_Configuration_Space_Access and I understand how to configure a PCI device through the IO ports of the CPU:

> Two 32-bit I/O locations are used, the first location (0xCF8) is named
>   CONFIG_ADDRESS, and the second (0xCFC) is called CONFIG_DATA.
>   CONFIG_ADDRESS specifies the configuration address that is required to
>   be accesses, while accesses to CONFIG_DATA will actually generate the
>   configuration access and will transfer the data to or from the
>   CONFIG_DATA register.

So in order to configure a PCI device I just need to put the configuration address that I want to configure and CONFIG_DATA is where I put the data. Both of these are I/O locations, so I ise I/O instructions in the CPU.

These two I/O locations give me access to a 256byte "big register" that I can use to configure the PCI device. All the fields of this big register are described in the OSDEV page. These 2 bits are of interest:

> Memory Space - If set to 1 the device can respond to Memory Space
>   accesses; otherwise, the device's response is disabled.
>
> I/O Space - If set to 1 the device can respond to I/O Space accesses;
>   otherwise, the device's response is disabled.

However apart from this, it's not clear on how to get or set the physical address space where each PCI device is going to respond

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> These two I/O locations give me access to a 256byte "big register" that I can use to configure the PCI device.

That "big register" is a structure with many fields. One of the fields is "Command Register", which contains global enable/disable flags, that can be used to disable the device's ability to send things to the bus (IRQs, writes from device to memory, etc)  and respond to things from the bus (writes from CPU to device, etc).

Other fields include "BARs" (Base Address Registers, starting at offset 0x10 in a device's configuration space) which tell the device which address range (in IO port space or physical address space) the device should accept. For these, a device will be hard-wired to use either IO ports or physical addresses (and that can not be changed) and the size of the area will also be hard-wired (and that can also not be changed). Because these things are hardwired, you can write zeros to a BAR and find out what was hardwired (to determine the size of the area, and if the device needs IO port space or physical address space).

Fortunately the firmware is responsible for configuring BARs, so (excluding hot-plug devices and "unusual circumstances") an OS doesn't need to set BARs itself, and can just read the value/s from the BARs (that were set by firmware) to determine the address (in IO port space or physical address space) that the device was already configured to use. Sadly, if the OS needs to determine the size of the area (e.g. and can't rely on the device driver knowing the size for its device already), an OS may need to read the firmware's value, then do the "write zeros to find out the size of the area", then restore the firmware's value.

Of course PCI configuration space won't say what the BARs are used for - it's up to the device driver to know what each area (described by each BAR) is used for.

If an OS wants to (re)configure BARs itself for whatever reason; then it's significantly more complex because you have to also make sure any bridges forward accesses to the device correctly (and if there's multiple devices behind a bridge then those devices must use sub-ranges in a single larger range that the bridge will forward); and you have to ensure that the CPU's caches don't ruin everything (which mostly means re-configuring the MTRRs/Memory Type Range Register on all CPUs at the same time with special synchronization); and you have to make sure you don't stomp on anything (e.g. ranges already used by firmware, RAM, CPU, etc); and have to make sure everything is in part of the physical address space that the CPU can access (even when the CPU has errata and reports the wrong "number of physical address bits" via. CPUID).

Comment: Thanks, I understood. There's only one 256 byte structure? I don't get how only one is responsible for al the PCI devices. Which part of the hardware informs about this structure fields? Is it a chip on the motherboard, which then redirects each PCI "packet" to each PCI device?

Comment: @LucasZanella: Oh, no - for "PCI conventional" there's one 256 byte structure for each different device or each "function" within a multi-function device. More correctly (using PCI's terminology) there's up to 256 buses, up to 32 devices per bus, and up to 8 functions per multi-function device; which gives a theoretical max. of 65536 functions and a max. of 65536 of the 256-byte structures. For PCI-E it got extended to 4096 bytes per function (if you use the newer memory mapped config space mechanism to access PCI configuration space instead of the IO ports).

Comment: @LucasZanella: The PCI configuration space for a device/function is built into that device/function. You use the IO ports to send a "request packet" saying "read 4 bytes from PCI config space for whatever is at bus:1,device:2, function:3" and bridges use the information in the packet to forward the packet to the right device on the right bus; then device itself gets the request, handles it, and sends a reply packet back (containing the bytes you asked to read from its function's PCI config space)

Comment: @LucasZanella: Don't forget that PCI is designed to allow you to plug anything you like into a PCI slot on the motherboard; which means that you can plug in a PCI bridge containing many devices into a single slot. Nothing on the motherboard can be "hard-wired" to support whatever random cards you felt like plugging in.

Comment: Ok, so using the 2 32 bit I/O locations at addresses `0xCF8` and `0xCFC` to talk to each 256 byte structure. To the first I/O location we pass a 32bit data that can select which BUS, which device on that BUS, and which function on that device. Then the other I/O location is where we pass or receive data (parts of the 256 byte structure) from the selected I/O location.

Comment: So when using these 2 32 bit I/O locations we're talking to the I/O "chip" that is connected to the CPU through the physical bus. This "chip" is connected to what? A PCI coordinator of some sort?

Comment: @LucasZanella: Yes (mostly) - the 32-bits from first IO port are "8-bit bus number, 5-bit device number, 3-bit function number, 8-bit offset" (plus some reserved bits and a few special flags if I remember right). Those IO ports are part of  "PCI host controller" (which is a special kind of bridge between whatever bus/link CPU uses and a PCI bus on the other side), which then forwards the onto the PCI bus (unless the request is for its own PCI config space). Of course "PCI host controller" is typically built into motherboard/chipset (or even into CPU now).